# By clicking a cancel button in the cell to delete that cell , and also delete the cell by editActionsForRowAt method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button

With `UITableView` edit method it working fine, but by using `UIButton` it's not working.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (deleteAction, indexPath) in
        deleteApm(Id: myString)
        self.AArrayList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
    return [deleteAction]
}

func deleteApm(Id:String)
{
    //...................................
}

@IBAction func myButt(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let cancelBtn = sender.tag
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ACell", for: indexPath) as! ATableViewCell
    cell.cancelBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myButt(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

Using this i called the same delete method in button but the delete not working using `UIButton`.
using `UITableView` its working fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the **tag** for your button in cellforRow , for identify the row or particular object

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ACell", for: indexPath) as! ATableViewCell
     cell.cancelBtn.tag = indexPath.row
     cell.cancelBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myButt(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
 }
```

and handle the action as

```
@IBAction func myButt(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    deleteApm( currentIndexpath: indexPath)

}
```

as well as in deleteRow in call

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (deleteAction, indexPath) in
        self.deleteApm(currentIndexpath: indexPath)           
    }
    return [deleteAction]
}
```

finally create the common method for delete api call

```
func deleteApm(currentIndexpath: IndexPath )    {
    let jsonDict = self.ArrayList[currentIndexpath.row] as? [String:Any]
    let Id:Int = jsonDict?["appointId"] as! Int
    let Id2 : Int = jsonDict?["appointId"] as! Int
    let param : [String : String] = ["pid": {String(Id2)}()]
    let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
    // "http://192.168.1.45:8080/zybrodental/patientApp/patientAppDeleteMultipleAppointment"

    Alamofire.request(APIMetadata.URL_DELETE_APPOINT, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case.success(let data):
            print("success",data)
             self.ArrayList.remove(at: currentIndexpath.row)
             self.yourtableViewName.deleteRows(at: [currentIndexpath], with: .fade)

        case.failure(let error):
            print("Not Success",error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting error in last line of code...    Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:) in    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

Comment: @SruthiCSankar - plz check the updated answer, and can you show your error

Comment: but i want to delete it from "func deleteApm" also

Comment: @SruthiCSankar- can you show that code of func deleteApm

Comment: @IBAction func myButt(_ sender: UIButton) {
       // let cancelBtn = sender.tag
        self.AArrayList.remove(at: sender.tag)
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        tblView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .fade)
    
    }

Comment: @SruthiCSankar - no no I am not asked this, i asked for this `"func deleteApm"` and check the updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191433/discussion-between-sruthi-c-sankar-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: error in "Extra argument 'currentIndexpath' in call"

Comment: @SruthiCSankar - can you show the error which line u faced this

Answer (score 0):

First Of All, You are using **Sender.tag** in `myButt(_ sender: UIButton)` function then, You have to assign that tag from `cellForRowAt` tableView Method.
Please use this `cellForRowAt` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ACell", for: indexPath) as? ATableViewCell
     cell?.lblText.text = "\(arrIndex[indexPath.row])"
     cell?.btnDelete.tag = indexPath.row
     cell?.btnDelete.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myButt(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

     return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
}
```

If you want to delete particular cell on delete button action event,Use this

```
@IBAction func myButt(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let cancelBtn = sender.tag
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: arrIndex.index(where: {$0 == "\(cancelBtn)"}) ?? 0, section: 0)
    self.arrIndex.remove(at: sender.tag)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```